# Second form not showing value stored in first form when called

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Hey all i am trying to figure out why my 2nd form is not displaying the value i recived in my first form.

The code for the first form is:

```
 Private Sub scannerOnCom_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    responceBack = scannerOnCom.ReadLine
    Call frm1110.clickButton(responceBack) 
 End Sub
```

The second form code is this:

```
Public Sub clickButton(ByRef theResponse As String)
    txtNumber.Text = theResponse
    'Call cmdNextFinish_Click(Nothing, Nothing)
End Sub
```

However, when i debug it to make sure there is something stored for theResponse, there is but for some reason it does not put it into the textbox. It's blank.

Any help would be great!

David

**UPDATE**

Ok so Form1:

```
Dim tmpForm3020 As New frm3020

Private Sub cmd3020_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmd3020.Click
    tmpForm3020.Show()
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
End Sub

Private Sub scannerOnCom_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    responceBack = scannerOnCom.ReadLine
    tmpForm3020.txtNumber.Text = responceBack
End Sub
```

If thats correct then i get an error on line:

**xForm.txtNumber.Text = responceBack**

Saying:

**Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'txtNumber' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.**

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim tmpForm3020 As New frm3020

Private Sub cmd3020_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmd3020.Click
    tmpForm3020.Show()
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
End Sub

Private Sub scannerOnCom_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    responceBack = scannerOnCom.ReadLine
    TestData(responceBack)
End Sub

Private Sub TestData(ByVal xVal As String)
   If InvokeRequired Then
      Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf TestData))
      ' change Me to tmpForm3020 (if it does not work)
      ' tmpForm3020.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf TestData))  
   Else
      tmpForm3020.txtNumber.Text = xVal
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That just opens another form (so now total of 3). All i want to do is put that value that was scanned into the txtbox of the form already opened. (form 2)

Comment: basically you cannot access winform controls inside the thread, all you have to do is to create a delegate

Comment: I did both suggestions "change me" in your code and i get **Method 'Private Sub TestData(xVal As String)' does not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Sub MethodInvoker()'.**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6848/discussion-between-stealthrt-and-johntotetwoo)

Answer (score 1):

Are you explicitly creating an instance of your second form, or relying on the default instance? I.e. is "frm1110" the second form's class name, or an instance that you have new'd up? Make sure in either case that it is the same instance that is actually being displayed.